# A Particular Weave Pattern

Tags: texturing, materials

[image]

Does anyone know how to make this particular weave pattern? It's basically just a checker texture, but the squares slightly overlap in the y axis, instead of being corner to corner. I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to offset the Y coordinate of the texture for every square along the X axis :

[image]

Playing with the offset:

[image]

Comment: Very nice :). It looked like a simple problem, until i tried it myself and failed miserably.

Comment: Yeah :) Playing with texture coordinates is a bit tricky, but once you get a hang of it, you up your shading game by a LOT